# Flexdashboard Error: object of type 'closure' is not subsetable, when using Reactive

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

I am trying to create a flexdashboard / shiny web app that reads a table from a SQL db, and based on the results of the query, creates a list of unique symbols, to display in a selector.

Once a unique symbol in selected, then it needs to display certain information for that symbol (from a SQL query), to later on display additional info from another SQL query in another table.

Since I am new to R and shiny, I am having problems trying to get this to behave the way I want. This is what I have:

### Column {.sidebar}

````
unique_symbols <- query_to_df(db, query_1)
selectInput('ticker', 'Ticker', unique_symbols$symbol)



```Column 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Selection

```{r}
reactive(unique_symbols %>% filter(symbol == input$ticker))
````

I get

[image]

Since for now I am only interested in the security_name field, I changed the code to this:

```
df <- reactive(unique_symbols %>% filter(symbol == input$ticker))
print(df$security_name)
```

And I get:

[image]
Why can't I access the elements of the df created with reactive? I have tried different solutions for similar problems posted here, but none works for me.

Comment: A reactive behaves like a function so you have to called it like a function. Try with `print(df()$security_name)`.

Comment: Thank you. I get: Error in : Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. * You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive consumer.

Comment: Aw. Sorry. You have to wrap the print statement inside `reactive()`, i.e. `reactive(print(df()$security_name))`

Comment: Thanks you @stefan, that worked. You should change your comments to answer so you get the points :-) Btw, the solution prints the first row of the df, like this [1] "Apple" (for example). How do you omit the index of the DF? Thanks again